# Что значит “кесаревом да по мясореву!”?

Tags: значения, сленг, морфология

Короткие описание игры про сумасшедшего хирурга:

> Surgeon Simulator — кесаревом да по мясореву!

Источник: http://stopgame.ru/appzor/show/36

Это вроде шутка? Я искал в словаре слова *кесарь* и *мясо*, но это мне не помогло.

Comment: Ага, значит что вопрос плохой. Только не знаю почему. :(

Comment: [Кесарево сечение](http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Comment: Наверное ради броского слогана намешали "Кесарево сечение" + "Кесарю - кесарево, слесарю - слесарево". Вместо слесаря взяли "мясо".

Comment: I personally see nothing wrong in this question. I wonder if the op would get downvotes if they asked for explanation of, say, "Vicodin? I'd like-o-din" on English.SE.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of those random, obnoxiously fruity colloquialisms that make a lot of people cringe, which may explain the downvotes. Кесаревым (properly so spelt) means "with a Caesarian [section]", мясорево is just мясо with an expressive suffix crudely plastered on. The construction "[noun-instrumental] по [noun-dative]" is common and versatile, "да" serves as an emphatic particle (you get it a lot in "rustic" speech and a register of vernacular that facetiously imitates it), and there's nothing wrong with using those per se, but this particular example is the true bottom of the barrel.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more note that may need to be added to Nikolay Ershov's analysis. The author of the pun (which betrays, as I wholeheartedly agree, a true linguistic bottom-dweller) employs a willful modification of the fairly recent derivation method increasingly characteristic of the modern jargon. This method derives nouns from verbs by using the suffix *-лов-* followed by the inflection *-о*.

One example of such nouns is the word *кидалово*. It derives from a jargon meaning of the verb *кидать*, *кинуть* - to manipulate one out of one's money or possessions through a deceitful transaction. The noun describes an act of such manipulation or an environment where it is likely to happen or known to have happened.

These new jargon nous look and sound not unlike the large class of Russian possessive adjectives formed by the suffix *–ов*. Where such adjectives have become toponyms (e.g. *Шереметьево*) they function as nouns, rather than adjectives, particularly in the instrumental case:

- *Я восхищён Ивáнов**ы**м талантом* - I admire Ivan's talent (although this example sounds quite archaic)
- *Я восхищён городом Ивáнов**о**м* - I admire the town of Ivanovo

The author of the pun seems to use the possessive adjective *кесарево* as a noun formed by the method described above, hence the erroneous instrumental ending *-ом*. She then applies the same method to the noun *мясо* trying at the same time to rhyme the product with *кесарево*. The result would undoubtedly fail the very first round of the auditions for the worst ever Christmas cracker joke.

See also:
http://community.lingvo.ru/goroda/articles.asp?article=43982&view=full

Comment: Очень интересная статья. Я даже нашел пример употребления слова “мясолово”: _Как раз на М6 я понял что танки это не тупое **мясолово**, а очень стратегическая игра и каждый танк из 15 так или иначе влияет на исход сражения, и теперь на любом танке у меня % побед 55+._ Только же здесь это слово означает незамысловатый игровой процесс, тупую стрельбу, а _по мясореву_, это просто по телу (мясу) пациента. Все верно понял?

Comment: > *по мясореву*, это просто по телу (мясу) пациента. Все верно понял? ----- Да, это верно.

Comment: > Только же здесь это слово означает незамысловатый игровой процесс.. -------

Я никогда не сталкивался со словом **мясолово**. Сталкивался с **месИлово** -- от *месить* (в значении "избивать", "уничтожать избыточным оружейным огнём"). Подозреваю, что *мясолово* это мутация *месилова*.

Comment: А я думал, что _мясолово_ в моем примере это _мясо_ ([Викисловарь, седьмое значение](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BE)) + _-лово_, суффикс о котором ты писал. Ну, о слове _месилово_ тоже интересно было узнать.

Comment: Да, действительно. Я никогда не знал о таком значении слова *мясо*. Очевидно, что моя гипотеза опровергнута. :)